# How to remove duplicate lines and preserve newlines, tabs, and spaces in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I have a file with thousands of lines, how would I have notepad++ remove duplicate lines (just like the built-in feature), but keep all the spacing?

If I use the built-in feature it deletes it all, the newlines, the tabs, the spaces, since all of those count as duplicates, but I need all the newlines, tabs, and spaces to stay.

For example, let's say this is the original text:

```
   Window 2

  notepad++ remove duplicate lines - Google Search
  https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+remove+duplicate+lines

  remove duplicate lines keep blank lines notepad++ - Google Search
  https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+duplicate+lines+keep+blank+lines+notepad

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/
```

After removing the duplicate lines, I want it to keep all the original spacing (while still keeping one original duplicate line), like this:

```
   Window 2

  notepad++ remove duplicate lines - Google Search
  https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+remove+duplicate+lines

  remove duplicate lines keep blank lines notepad++ - Google Search
  https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+duplicate+lines+keep+blank+lines+notepad

  YouTube
  https://www.youtube.com/
```

I've tried doing this a couple ways using methods I've found online, like the second answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad), and a couple other similar methods, none doing what I want it to.

To be honest, I just need a way to do this in general, doesn't necessarily have to be in notepad++, but if there's a way to do it, then I'd rather stick to notepad++.

Comment: Are the data always within 2 lines?

Comment: @Toto Yes, the data will always look exactly like how it looks in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution replaces two consecutive identical triplets with one,
so you will have to run it repeatedly until it finds no more of them.
I assume that the blank line is truly blank with no blank characters.

Find what : `^(.*?$\r\n.*?$\r\n\r\n)\1`
Replace with : `\1`
Search mode : Regular expression with ". matches newline".

[image]

Comment: I followed what you said, and used the same text as in the example I gave above, but it just comes back that 0 occurrences were replaced. For whatever reason, it can't find "^(.*?$\r\n.*?$\r\n\r\n)\1", does your solution work for you with the example block of text I gave above?

Comment: I tested of course. The blank line is not empty or some other difference in your data.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was on my end. Got it all working now, thanks!